# Paypal DonationForm not passing dropdown option name item to paypal

Tags: forms, paypal

This code is not passing the dropdown item name to paypal. I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <!-- If using a Business or Company Logo Graphic, include the "cpp_header_image" variable in your View Cart code. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or Account ID -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="testemail@paypal.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="WF-1001">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after a successful transaction -->
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mullumseed.org.au/thankyou">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after item cancellation -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" 
value="https://mullumseed.org.au/cancel">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<!-- -->Please enter your donation amount: (Example - 10.00)<br><br>
    <input type="text" name="amount" size="5">
<br><br>Choose Your Organization:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="item_name">
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Byron Shire Chemical Free Landcare" selected>Byron Shire Chemical Free Landcare</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Corem">Corem</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullum Seed Inc">Mullum Seed Inc</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullum Community Garden">Mullum Community Garden</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullum Cares">Mullum Cares</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullum Mens Shed">Mullum Mens Shed</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullum Food Coop">Mullum Food Coop</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Shara Community Gardens">Shara Community Gardens</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Reforest Now">Reforest Now</option>
    <option value="Widget Fund Donation - Mullumbimbees">Reforest Now</option>
   </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Tax Deductable Email Receipt Requested">Would you like a Tax Deductable Email Receipt?&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <INPUT NAME="os1" type="radio" value="Yes" checked>Yes
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <INPUT NAME="os1" type="radio" value="No Thanks">No Thanks<br><br>
<!-- -->
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leftover line 6

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name">
```

Comment: you are the best :-)